# Transferring a live chat to another agent doesn't show all the records from creation

Tags: liveagent

**Scenario:**

- We are using the Deployment API to do a findOrCreate on a form and we successfully initiate a chat and either find or created **two different records** from two different Salesforce objects. One is a custom object and one is a standard object (Contact).
- We rely on transferring chats to another representative if the customer changed their interest, etc.

**Problem:**
If you transfer the chat with the two created tabs, the new agent accepts and is shown the chat with only 1 tab for the contact record.

This appears to be something that changed in Spring 14:

> Starting in Spring ’14, the Related Entities panel in the details tab isn’t available for new Live Agent customers. Existing customers will continue to have access to the Related Entities panel.
>
> However, new and existing customers now have another option for linking new and existing records to chat transcripts: using the freshly minted attachment tool, available in this release. For more information about the attachment tool, see Attach Records to Chat Transcripts.

When you view the "Attachment Tool" dropdown on the record on the initial chat, both records are in fact there. Once we transfer the chat, there is only the standard object record and we are not presented with any "Unsaved changes" dialogs or anything on that sort.

Has anyone else experienced this or know what might be causing this to occur?

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar issue at NOWTV. We use the findOrCreate script to link the chat to a case and a contact, but once the chat is transferred to another agent, the related lists are cleared ...
I raised the issue with salesforce and was told that it is "working as designed" - i.e. they are not going to fix it ...

I create an idea for it - I'd appreciate if you can vote on it and perhaps get your users to vote as well, we'll need some critical mass to get this to the top of the pile ...

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l81WAAQ